# Java Package NHLstats Import Issue

Tags: java, import, ide

Apologies if this is not allowed. I have been going through the mooc.fi learning java course and seem to be stuck on exercise 13.

The course gives you a pre-built package and asks you to do various tasks with the package.

After downloading the package and running in IntelliJ I am getting the error "java: Package nhlstats does not exist".

I have tried re-naming one "NHLTest" class to "nhlstats" however I still seem to be getting the error. Apologies if this seems a simple question but I can't seem to get my head around Java package structure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgNwM.jpg (Screenshot to IDE)

Java: Package nhlstats does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I had not set the libraries directory under "File | Project Structure | Libraries" in IntelliJ so I don't think it could find the class to import.